# How to register a disposable Concrete type in Simple Injector container

Tags: c#, idisposable, simple-injector

I found the following code at [Simple Injector Website](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped)

```cs
public static void RegisterDisposableTransient<TService, TImplementation>(
    this Container container)
    where TImplementation : class, IDisposable, TService
    where TService : class
{
    var scoped = Lifestyle.Scoped;
    var reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<TService, TImplementation>(
        container);

    reg.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
            "suppressed.");

    container.AddRegistration(typeof(TService), reg);
    container.RegisterInitializer<TImplementation>(
        o => scoped.RegisterForDisposal(container, o));
}
```

I want to register a concrete implementation (one that does not implement any particular interface) that is Disposable for the transient scope. What changes do I need to make to the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to register a concrete disposable type, typically the simplest (and best) thing to do is to register it as `Scoped`:

```
container.Register<MyConcrete>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

In case you really need that instance to be transient (unlikely), you will have to do the following.

It's just a matter of using the `CreateRegistration<TConcrete>` overload:

```
public static void RegisterDisposableTransient<TConcrete>(this Container container)
    where TConcrete : class, IDisposable
{
    var scoped = Lifestyle.Scoped;
    var reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<TConcrete>(container);

    reg.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, "suppres");

    container.AddRegistration(typeof(TConcrete), reg);
    container.RegisterInitializer<TConcrete>(
        o => scoped.RegisterForDisposal(container, o));
}
```

Comment: The final line (`scoped.RegisterForDisposal`) throws an exception. Is it OK to remove that final line? The whole point was this was supposed to not be scoped, but transient, which throws however if the service type (TConcrete) implements IDisposable. The idea here is the user is handling disposal, which is particularly needed when in a console app or web service. The alternative is we have to reference the container itself to call BeginScope on etc, but that requires referencing the container throughout the app! The big no no, when we can dispose are our own objects. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Btw, @Steven's (excellent) documentation covers this issue [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html), but in the same way, using a scope in the final line, when I thought the whole point was it was registering as a transient, i.e. where there shouldn't be a scope handling disposal. The whole issue is often we don't have a scope (so that final line throws an exception). The purpose of registering transient is when we ourselves handle disposal.

Comment: Your design raises some questions for me, so it would be good to post a new question explaining what you are doing, what kind of disposable object this is andhow the application interacts.with it. This allows me to give a more specific answer. Besides, it's interesting to see the details of the exception being thrown.

Comment: I have a few of these so I created a helper method which is used in my configureContainer method:  

    private static void registerConcreteDisposable<T>() where T : class {
            var reg = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<T>(container);
            reg.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, "suppres");
            container.AddRegistration(typeof(T), reg);
        }